# Polycarbonate resistant to chemical

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

Why polycarbonate couldn't stand some chemicals i.e. acid and base? What reaction will occur if polycarbonate meets acid or base?

Answer (score 1):

Strong acids or bases will hydrolyze polycarbonate resin--specifically poly(bisphenol A carbonate)--at the ester linkages, first giving shorter polycarbonate chains, and eventually down to bisphenol A and carbonate ion or carbon dioxide.